# Staged migration exchange 2003 to office 365

Tags: migration, outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-365

I have been tasked with migrating our corporate exchange server to office 365 :(.

The current configuration is as follows.

1: Web facing "outlook web access" on windows 2003 sp2 server
1: Exchange 2003 SP2 Mail Server on windows 2003 sp2 server

I have to perform a staged migration.

My concerns are as follows.  I am following the documentation @ http://help.outlook.com/en-US/140/ff959224.aspx and all seems fine apart from outlook anywhere.  Can I install outlook anywhere side by side with OWA or do I need a completely different server?  Do I need to configure outlook anywhere will OWA suffice.  Has anybody performed this migration before and if so can you highlight any pitfalls etc.

I have approx 110 - 120 GB of mailboxes to migrate.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

David

Comment: I'm guessing you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation again and again I noticed that I missed the work "or".  (RPC / HTTP) or Qutlook Anywhere.

Outlook Web Access works with (RPC / HTTP) :)

The Exchange Remote Connectivity Analyser tool executed successfully against outlook web access.